# R Programming: How to show data labels in rCharts?

Tags: r

I have a bar chart where I want to show the value of the bar above each bar.  However, using showValues results in the plot not working.  Any ideas?

```
data2plot <-data.frame(Status=c("Open","Closed","Blocked"),Count=c(200,300,400))     

a <- nPlot(Count ~ Status, data = data2plot, type = "multiBarChart")
a$chart(showValues=TRUE)
a
```

I'm using nplot, the nvd3 version.  I'm open to changing to something else if I need to.

Comment: the values show if you hover over the bars

Comment: I know, but I'm creating a page with a lot of these charts and I'd like the value to be visible at a glance

Comment: in that case, doesn't a static chart work better?

Comment: Yes I could make it static and do this but I would like to know how to accomplish this with rCharts

Comment: @NicE, that worked! Do you know how to adjust the significant digits?  My label with a value of 10 became 10.00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change `type` to `discreteBarChart`. To format the values displayed, you can use `valueFormat`, which takes a Javascript function and applies it to the values. [Here](http://koaning.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/html/d3format.html) is some info on `d3.format` function.

```
library(rCharts)
a <- nPlot(Count ~ Status, data = data2plot, type = "discreteBarChart")
a$chart(showValues=TRUE)
a$chart(valueFormat="#!d3.format('d')!#")
a
```

[image]